# Docker named volumes vs DOC (data-only-containers)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Up to recent version of Docker (v1.10), we were thought that we can use DOC: *data-only containers*. So I would create such DOC (based on e.g. busybox) and use `--volumes-from` to link it to my container. You can still read about this in [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container).

With new version of docker, it is said that instead of DOC we should use `named volumes`. Here is an example of `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'    
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:2.2.0
    command: elasticsearch -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "9201:9200"
    volumes:
      - "es-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"

volumes:    
  es-data:
```

Here we created and use named volume `es-data`.

There is still not much documentation on this new feature. I am asking:

- Can we replace DOC with named containers? How long volume is persisted? What if I remove the container that is using it?
- How can we e.g. backup now? Previously, I could `docker run --rm --volumes-from es-data ...` and then `tar` it.

Comment: "Can we replace..."? - see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17798#issuecomment-154815207

Comment: FYI "based on e.g. busybox" - it's considered wrong, check [Data-only container madness](http://container42.com/2014/11/18/data-only-container-madness/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Can we replace DOC with named containers?

In many cases, yes, named containers will be a better option.

> How long volume is persisted? What if I remove the container that is using it?

If you remove the container, the volume will still be there. The only way to remove the volume is to use `docker-compose down -v` or `docker volume rm <volume name>`.

> How can we e.g. backup now? Previously, I could docker run --rm --volumes-from es-data ... and then tar it.

Instead of `--volumes-from`, you can use `--volume=<volume name>`.

Note that volumes created by `docker-compose` are always prefixed with the project name, so if you use it with a `docker` command the full name is actually `<project_name>_es-data`.

Comment: compose supports mounting [external](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external) volumes, no prefix in this case

Comment: I'd love to see an example of this.

Comment: But in this case, compose won't create the volume itself, it has to exist already.

Comment: I see we can create a named volume by giving a name instead of an absolute path on the host, as in: `-v learnintouch-data:/usr/bin/mysql/install/data` instead of `-v /home/stephane/dev/php/learnintouch/docker/mysql/data:/usr/bin/mysql/install/data`. But when can I associate the volume name `learnintouch-data` with the host location at `/home/stephane/dev/php/learnintouch/docker/mysql/data`?

Comment: You can't. A volume is either a named volume or a host bind mount.