# SQLServer Docker: How do I backup & restore the data *volume*?

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a MS SQLServer 2017 Linux Docker container running with docker-compose. (Working on
a Windows host.)
The server is running, I added data, and this data is persistent across multiple `docker-compose up / down`
since the server uses a **docker volume**. The data disappears when I use `docker-compose down -v`. So ***this works as intended:***

```
services:
    sql:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-GA-ubuntu
        volumes:
         - sqldata:/var/opt/mssql
        ...

volumes:
    sqldata:
        driver: local
        name: sqldata
```

Now I am trying to backup & restore the database. I know the "normal" way, using the SQLServer directly. ***This works:***

```
# Restore a backup inside the container volume
docker exec -it sql mkdir /var/opt/mssql/backup
docker cp .\Test.bak sql:/var/opt/mssql/backup
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1,1433 -U sa -P Secr3tSA_Passw0rd -H 127.0.0.1,1433 -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [Test] FROM DISK='/var/opt/mssql/backup/Test.bak' WITH REPLACE"

# Backup a database inside the container volume, then copy to local file
docker exec sql rm -rf /var/opt/mssql/backup/Test.bak
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1,1433 -U sa -P Secr3tSA_Passw0rd -H 127.0.0.1,1433 -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [Test] TO DISK='/var/opt/mssql/backup/Test.bak'"
docker cp sql:/var/opt/mssql/backup/Test.bak .\Test.bak
```

Now I was thinking, maybe there is a better way than to put the SA password into a BAT file
and hand that out to my customers and service technicians. Simply grabbing a copy of the volume
should do the trick!

I found this:

```
# Make sure the SQLServer is not writing/blocking any files.
docker-compose stop sql

# Backup & Restore the sqldata volume.
docker run --rm -v sqldata -v $pwd\backup:/backup ubuntu bash -c "cd /whsqldata && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar --strip 1"
docker run --rm -v sqldata -v $pwd\backup:/backup ubuntu bash -c "cd /whsqldata && tar cvf /backup/backup.tar ."

# Restart the SQLServer.
docker-compose start sql
```

This creates the expected backup.tar in my user directory... But it is suspiciously small! And after the
restore, the SQLServer cannot connect to the database. **It looks like the backup.tar has no content.**
But on closer inspection, so has my sqldata volume! It is empty!? When I start a bash that mounts that
same volume, I can see the directory but there is nothing in it:

```
docker run --rm -v sqldata -it ubuntu
/ # ls sqldata/ -a
. ..
/ #
```

The SQLServer´s data persists. So it´s got to be saved *somewhere*, right? What am I missing?!

Answer (score 2):

OK, after reading the answers to [How should I backup & restore docker named volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298645/how-should-i-backup-restore-docker-named-volumes) I found out that my mistake was in how I mounted the volume. Instead of `-v sqldata` I have to write `-v sqldata:/sqldata`. Also changed some paths in my commands.

The completed commands are:

```
# Backup the data volume
docker run --rm \
       -v sqldata:/sqldata \
       -v $pwd\:/backup \
       ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /sqldata

# Remove existing data volume (clear up old data, if exists)
docker volume rm sqldata

# Restore the data volume
docker run --rm \
       -v sqldata:/sqldata \
       -v $pwd\:/backup \
       ubuntu tar xvf /backup/backup.tar -C sqldata --strip 1
```