# How to correctly specify named volumes when trying to backup files in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have the below docker-compose file

```
version: '2'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=42EXP

  node:
    container_name: node
    build: .
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    command: npm start

volumes:
  postgresdata:
```

on running `docker volume ls` i have

```
local               42exp_postgresdata
```

When trying to perform a backup through:

```
docker run --rm --volume=42exp_postgresdata -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

i get the below error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Invalid volume spec "42exp_postgresdata": Invalid volume destination path: '42exp_postgresdata' mount path must be absolute..
```

I'm not sure where i'm going wrong since its pretty much the exact code specified in the docs. How do i properly specify a named volume to backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mount the volume somewhere:

```
docker run --rm -v 42exp_postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data -v $(pwd):/backup \
    ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

EDIT:

Note that `-v | --volume` option has many formats. You can use it to bind-mount folders from host to container:

```
-v /folder/on/host:/folder/in/container
```

mount named volumes to container:

```
-v named-volume:/folder/in/container
```

or just to specify un-named volumes for container:

```
-v /this/folder/in/container/will/be/stored/in/volume
```

Comment: You're right - it works. thanks :D. Do you think my compose.yml is fine or are there any glaring mistakes that you see? there are tonnes of tutorials specifiying different ways to write it.

Comment: I think it's fine. If you are just starting with docker-compose, check out also ansible modules for docker http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_cloud_modules.html#docker It provides similar functionality, but with ansible, you can manage way more stuff. (I use ansible and I like it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `--volumes-from mycompose_postgres_1` (or whhatever your resulting docker image is called)? See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

Comment: it looks like volumes-from is used for volume containers ... i have to use `--volume={name} ` for named volumes. But it still doesnt seem to work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011595/docker-named-volumes-vs-doc-data-only-containers